# Download video (webinar) - Comsol

Tags: video, download

How could I download the following video (registration is needed)?

https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/2478364463026952706

The only way that I know is with a screen recorder software like camtasia studio, but it takes much time. I'd like to use a chrome's extension (flash video downloader does not work).

Thank you.

Comment: The people hosting the webinar are the ones who have access to and can provide a download of the webinar. You should contact them.

Answer (score -2):

There is usually a download button.

https://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/Webinar/all_files/G2W040007

If it doesn't work. Try using Firefox as mentioned in this thread:

https://community.gotomeeting.com/gotomeeting/topics/not-able-to-download-sessions-recording-getting-this-error-the-saas-g2w-cbr-prod-usstandard-s3-amazonaws-com-page-isn

Comment: This is at least the second question you've posted a link-only answer to today. Link-only answers are not acceptable for the reasons we mentioned in comments on your previous answer. Please include relevant information FROM the link IN you post, and use the link for reference and further information ONLY.

Comment: The Citrix document you linked appears to note that there are only downloads of recordings YOU have made, while OP appears to be trying to download a recording of a meeting he attended.

Comment: The download button is the "relevant information FROM" the first link. Using firefox is the relevant information from the second. I am not sure how much duplication of information you are expecting. Should I copy pictures and all from another acceptable answer?

Comment: All of the information necessary for a good answer should be here. The link is only for attribution and further research but should not be necessary.